# How to install and use VerySimpleXML in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I am new to Delphi and I need help in how to install VerySimpleXML.  I would also greatly appreciate a tutorial on how to use it to convert html to xml, if you guys know where I can find such a tutorial.

Answer (score 6):

I've downloaded the [VerySimpleXML](http://blog.spreendigital.de/2011/11/10/verysimplexml-a-lightweight-delphi-xml-reader-and-writer/) and it is a single pas file, so there's nothing to install.

To make this unit available to your project(s) you basically can:

1. Put the file anywhere in your disk and *add the file to every project* where you want to use it. To add the file to the project use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd> or via menú in Project/Add to project
2. Put the file anywhere in your disk and then add that folder to your Delphi *library path*, globally in Tools/Options/Delphi Options/Library/Library Path.
3. Put the file anywhere in your disk and then add that folder to your Project *search path*, in Project/Options/Delphi-Compiler/Search Path.
4. Put the file in the same folder where your project (dpr) file resides

Once the file is available to the project, you just add `Xml.VerySimple` to your `uses` clause in any unit you want to use it, for example:

```
Unit myUnit;
interface
  //whatever

implementation
uses Xml.VerySimple;
```

The download comes with an example that you may study to learn how to use it.